# Printf() in c printing 0's for extra format specifiers

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,*b,**c,***d,****e;
    a=10;
    b=&a;
    c=&b;
    d=&c;
    e=&d;
    printf("\na=%d b=%u c=%u d=%u e=%u",a,b,c,d,e);
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d",a,a+*b,**c+***d+****e);
    return 0;
}
```

I could not edit this post... All the options to do so are not visible to my browser.I meant to ask why the compiler didnt warn me and is giving me the output as 0 0 for the extra format specifiers.

Comment: Frankly, you're lucky it's 0 that is printed. Not passing a value for a format specifier will result in something random being put out. Something further up the stack in the old days, or the contents of a register possibly.

Comment: The compiler didn't warn you because you didn't configure it to do so. I can't tell you how to do so because I can't guess what compiler your have. You don't care why it printed out 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect it to print when given five conversion specifications but only three arguments?

The C standard says, in `7.19.6.1/2`

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, the program happend to print zeroes. In my case, it printed something else.

EDIT in response to the question "why?": Most compilers do warn about this error:

gcc says `warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument`

clang says `warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments`

icc says `warning #267: the format string requires additional arguments`

However, there is no requirement that they must diagnose this. Undefined behavior is just that, undefined. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

You have not provided enough parameters to your second call to `printf` and have invoked undefined behaviour. Please refrain from doing this. Your compiler should warn about this if you configure its warnings appropriately,